# File upload path in a test

Tags: testing, grails, geb

A geb test tests file upload in a grails application. According to the [documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.0/navigator.html#file_upload) the absolute path of the file has to be specified in the test. Is it possible to make the test a bit more portable between developers/machines by including a file in the grails source tree and then getting its absolute path from the geb test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using `System.properties['base.dir']` to get real path to my application.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in doing something like this

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/

In the **Get file path example** he creates a temporal file and then gets its filePath. If you need a specific file then I recomend you to build / write on it after creating it, this way you have a User/enviroment free file to access from your app anytime.

I ran into a problem like this once, uploading a photo to a server with grails, and for test or repetitive actions I created it and added the base64 code on runtime.

Hope it helps. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String cd = new File(".").getAbsolutePath().replace(".","");
String file = cd + "file.jpg"
println file
```

It's work for me, on windows an linux.
it's need for CI and local building test.